# Get the Sum of all fields in a Django queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to Sum fields across records in queryset.  I basically want the sum of every field.

I doing this as follows:

```
field_names = MyModel._meta.get_fields()
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(some filter criteria)

for fn in field_names:
    result = queryset.aggregate(Sum(fn.name))
    actual = result[fn.name+'__sum']
```

This is obviously and outrageously inefficient.  How do I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inefficiency is likely due to the fact that for every column, you perform a query. As a result for 20 fields, you perform 20 queries.

Making queries is typically expensive, and a significant amount of type is "query-independent" in the sense that it takes time, regardless what the query itself is supposed to do: one needs to create the query, pass it to the database, then the database needs to come up with a "query execution plan", then perform the query, and communicate the response back. Although of course the query itself takes some time, as you can see there are some other tasks that need to run as well, *per* query. So even if the queries are very cheap, they consume considerable resources. If the filtering is however non-trivial as well (not something that can easily be resolved with indexes), we also do a lot of duplicated work to determine what rows of the table to take into account.

You can do this all in **one** aggregate by first using *list comprehension*, and then passing it as `*args`:

```py
result = queryset.aggregate(*[Sum(fn.name) for fn in field_names])
```

Now `result` is a dictionary that maps all those fields to their corresponding sum, something like:

```
#  example result
result == { 'foo__sum': 42, 'bar__sum': 14, 'qux__sum': 52 }
```

The query will thus look like:

```sql
SELECT SUM(foo) AS foo__sum, SUM(bar) AS bar__sum, SUM(qux) AS qux__sum
FROM mymodel
WHERE 1 = 1  -- some filter conditions
```

Therefore all the aggregates are calculated in the *same* query.

> **Note**: since `field_names` is a collection of fields, and not the name of the fields, I advise to rename this variable to `fields` instead, to avoid any confusion later.

Comment: Thanks and amended `field_names` as recommended